# Header Strict-Transport-Security

Tags: apache, hsts

When I add the header `Strict-Transport-Security` to my .htaccess file, in Apache, must the browser block all HTTP requests?

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I add the header Strict-Transport-Security to my .htaccess file, in Apache, must the browser block all HTTP requests?

No it will not block them, it will instead automatically convert them to HTTPS before sending them.

But only after it’s got that instruction to use HSTS.

Also if you stop supporting HTTPS then you will not be able to connection to your site using HTTP as the browser will convert all the requests to HTTPS.